# Union of unit balls are measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This problem is an exercise from the *Walter Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.*

Prove that an uncountable union of close balls in $R^n$ is measurable.

The hint shows that we should prove that the boundary of this set has measure zero, but I don't know how to estimate the measure.

Comment: Are you sure about the exercise? The closest one is Ex.20 in chapter 7 which asks about uncountable unions of closed discs. (an arbitrary union of open sets is open, i.e., it's a Borel set.)

Comment: As others have said, this appears to be misstated. Of possible use (I haven't given it any thought) is the fact that one can show using the Vitali covering lemma that an arbitrary union of non-degenerate intervals in $\mathbb R$ is Lebesgue measurable (this used to be a sometimes-asked real analysis Ph.D. qualifying question at Indiana University in the 1960s and 1970s). In fact, by rather straightforward methods, one can show that an arbitrary union of non-degenerate intervals is an $F_{\sigma}$ set (see proof of Theorem 2.3 on p. 42 of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821869906)).

Comment: Sorry, it should be close balls.

Comment: The Vitali covering theorem is in the chapter...

Comment: I don't know how to solve the question using this....@GEdgar

Comment: **Hint:** Here's a proof for ${\mathbb R}.$ Let $\mathcal I$ be an arbitrary collection of non-degenerate intervals, and let $\mathcal A$ be the collection of all non-degenerate intervals each of which is a subset of at least one interval in ${\mathcal I}.$ Then $\mathcal A$ is a Vitali covering of $E \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \cup {\mathcal I}.$ Let $\mathcal J \subseteq \mathcal I$ be a countable subcollection of $\mathcal I$ such that $E - \cup \mathcal J$ has zero Lebesgue outer measure. Then $E=(\cup \mathcal J) \cup (E-\cup \mathcal J)$ shows that $E$ is the union of two measurable sets.

Comment: @GEdgar: It appears I was mistaken about the IU Ph.D. qualifying exams. I checked my records, and none of the exams from Fall 1968 to Fall 1982 have this result for intervals. I've known this result since I was there, so I strongly suspect this was a homework problem (or lecture observation) in a 2-semester real analysis course I took there in 1982-83 (under Torchinsky). Incidentally, although an arbitrary union of intervals is actually an $F_{\sigma}$ set, the higher dimensional version for closed rectangles or closed balls can fail to be a Borel set. **(continued)**

Comment: Let $P$ be a non-Borel subset of the reals and for each $x \in P$ let $B_x$ be a closed ball in ${\mathbb R}^2$ whose intersection with the real line is $\{x\}.$ Then the union of these closed balls is not a Borel set, because the intersection of this union with the real line is not a Borel set.

Comment: This appears in the Chapter 7: Differentiation, I guess Lebsgue Point should be used to solve the problem.